# Swift: How can I bind an NSIndexPath to a addTarget

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UISwitch` in each of my dynamically created rows of which I want to bind an NSIndexPath to an addTarget selector.

I had considered allowing the user to tap the row to toggle the switch, but from a UX perspective it makes more sense to have the switch handle this method, therefore using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not an appropriate solution.

When my cell is created I currently bind a selector like this:

```
// Create listener for each switch
prefCell.subscribed?.addTarget(self, 
                               action: "switchFlipped:",
                               forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Which calls the corresponding method:

```
func switchFlipped(flipSwitch: UISwitch, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {}
```

Obviously this throws an error  because `NSIndexPath` isn't a valid reference, as I believe it will only send the buttons reference.  Is there any way I can bind the index path? If not, is there any way to get the current cell from the context of the `UISwitch`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The target-action pattern does not allow arbitrary selectors. You can have `f(sender:)` and `f(sender:event:)`. Both won't help you. But you can use code to figure out the indexPath in the function.

Code should be self explanatory:

```
func switchFlipped(flipSwitch: UISwitch) {
    let switchOriginInTableView = flipSwitch.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: tableView)
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(switchOriginInTableView) {
        println("flipped switched at \(indexPath)")
    }
    else {
        // this should not happen
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but will it work for having multiple sections?

Comment: @Alex Yes it will. I should probably steal it and add to my answer as well :P

Comment: @Matthias Can I add your solution to the list of mine?

Comment: Where is this code going to exist? In the code for the custom cell? Then you still need to give the cell a reference to its tableview, which violate MVC. Not only that but if the cell executes some code that takes a non-trivial amount of time to execute, the cell could be scrolled off-screen and deallocated before the operation finishes, which may cause errors. There's no good reason to rely on where controls are located in the UI in this case; it's a wonky solution. This kind of thing is what delegation is meant for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try 3 approaches, as you see fit.

1. Create a custom UISwitch class and add an NSIndexPath property to it. When you receive notification, type cast to your custom class and access the NSIndexPath.
2. Create a custom UITableViewCell class and save NSIndexPath to it. When you get notified of UISwitch, get its superviews and see which one is your customUITableViewCell instance and get the property.
3. If you only have one section, it means all you need to worry about are rows. Set the UISwitch tag as the row number and access it when switch is flipped.
4. **The Most Tech-Savy Solution** Use Extensions of Swift.

> Extensions add new functionality to an existing class, structure, or enumeration type. This includes the ability to extend types for which you do not have access to the original source code 
>   [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)

Comment: I like the idea of setting an index path that sounds like exactly what I need!

Comment: Accepted your answer as it highlights a wide range of techniques to implement what I am after, thanks for your time :)

Comment: Just moved over to iOS from Android so this is pretty new to me haha

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is no good solution in this post. Your indexpath is going to change as the tableview reuses cells, and telling each cell what its indexpath is and making a named variable for it is all kinds of dirty and violates MVC. The better practice would be to use delegation as in my response below.

Comment: @user2320861 Firstly I've used such solutions myself so I know that these work. Secondly, when I said set the IndexPath, I mean to set it every time in cellForIndexPath. Thirdly, the solution I gave was to figure out which NSIndexPath it belonged to, not how the entire architecture should swing.

Comment: I'm sure it works if in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you tell each cell what it's index path is. But the point of MVC is that the cell shouldn't have to know, nor should the cell be handling any operations involving the switch action. What if the cell is deallocated while an operation is still running? A user could flip a switch and then scroll before the operation finishes. It's much cleaner and more robust to use the delegate pattern. I'm sure any of your solutions would work. Neither is using the delegate pattern swinging the entire architecture of the app. It's simply a better practice.

Comment: @user2320861 My good sir, you are correct as well. What about extensions? That is MVC, right?

Comment: I guess it depends on what the implementation in the extension is lol. If you wanted *every* instance of a class to implement the new extension method then class extensions would be appropriate. I'm not sure how one would use extensions in this case, though. The cell would still need to communicate "down" to its tableview that some action was performed on its switch. I guess you could extend UISwitch to perform some operation asynchronously, but at some point you would still need to violate MVC to tell the switch what its index path is.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the a good solution, not depending on a point. You call the superviews of the Switch and therefore calculate the index path of the cell.

```
func switchTapped(sender: UISwitch) -> NSIndexPath {
    let cell = sender.superview!.superview! as UITableViewCell
    return tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!
}
```

This reliably works, that's why you can simply unwrap any optionals.

Comment: This reliable works in all known versions of iOS 7 and iOS 8. It does not work in iOS 6 and it might fail in iOS 9. You should not rely on the view hierarchy of objects you don't own. Apple has changed the hierarchy before and they might change it again. In iOS 6 you needed on `superview!` less, because the new UITableContentScrollView did not exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use delegation.

Your switch's target action should be a method in your custom UITableViewCell. That custom tableviewcell should declare a protocol and the tableview should be it's delegate. Then your tableviewcell should call its delegate method from within the switch's target function.

The delegate method for your tableviewcell should have a parameter in which the cell passes `self`. Then in your tableviewcontroller delegate implementation you can use `indexPathForCell:`

UPDATE:

Here is the apple doc for swift protocols and delegates:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Simply put, you need to define a protocol

```
protocol CustomUITableViewCellDelegate {
    func tableViewCellSubscribed(cell: myCustomUITableViewCell) -> Void
}
```

then you make your tableviewcontroller class conform to that protocol like this:

```
class myTableViewController: UITableViewController, CustomUITableViewCellDelegate {

func tableViewCellSubscribed(cell: myCustomUITableViewCell) -> Void {
    //this is where you handle whatever operations you want to do regarding the switch being valuechanged
}

// class definition goes here
}
```

Then your custom UITableViewCell class should have a delegate property like this:

```
class myCustomUITableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    var delegate : CustomUITableViewCellDelegate?

    //class definition goes here
}
```

Finally, set the cell's delegate in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and you're good to go. You just need to call your `tableViewCellSubscribed:` delegate function from within the target method of your switch action.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm knew to this - could you possibly post a short code snippet?

Comment: I see, worked a treat - thanks man :) really simple when you see the code in practice not sure why I hadn't thought of this before!

Comment: Did you get it working that fast? neat stuff man. Protocols and delegates were pretty opaque to me when I first started looking at them, but now I use them all the time.

Comment: Yeah man I can see how they're useful, I think the names of the principles are more scary than the implementation lol.  Thanks again

Comment: no problem, I'm going to elaborate on the answer just for posterity's sake

Answer (score 0):

I've used this approach in many projects, you can just add a callback to your custom cell, each time your switch changes, you can run this callback and catch it inside your table datasource implementation, below a dirt and simple example.

#### 1. Create a UITableViewCell custom class

```
// An example of custom UITableViewCell class

class CustomCell:UITableViewCell {

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
  
  var onSwitchChange:() -> Void?
  
}

class TableDataSource:UITableViewDataSource {
  
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
  }
  
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as CustomCell
    cell.onSwitchChange = {
      NSLog("Table: \(tableView) Cell:\(cell) Index Path: \(indexPath)")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acctually,Apple has already provide API to get the indexPath.
Simply like this (in Objective-C)

`NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];`

Answer (score 0):

Far easier, you can use the `tag` variable for this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    cell.mySwitch.tag = indexPath.item
    cell.mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    ...
}

func switchChanged(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
    let indexPathItem = mySwitch.tag
    ...
}
```

From official doc :

> ***var tag: Int { get set }***
>
> An integer that you can use to identify view objects in your
> application.
>
> The default value is 0. You can set the value of this tag
> and use that value to identify the view later.