# Why does my delegate always receive a nil cell

Tags: ios, swift

I thought I had solved my problem earlier when I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477591/swift-how-can-i-bind-an-nsindexpath-to-a-addtarget). However I am now encountering a new problem, which always passes a nil cell to my ValueChanged method on a UISwitch.  As suggested in the answer to my previous question I implemented a protocol for my UITableViewController to implement, the protocol exists inside my custom cell view:

```
// Protocol
protocol SwitchValueChangedDelegate {
    func switchChanged(cell: PreferenceCell) -> Void
}

// Custom cell class
class PreferenceCell : UITableViewCell {
    var delegate : SwitchValueChangedDelegate?

    // Class body here...
}
```

I believe this to be valid, my UITableViewController then implements this protocol:

```
class PreferencesTableViewController: UITableViewController, 
                                      SwitchValueChangedDelegate 
{
      // Class body here
}
```

In order to conform to the protocol I implement the required method:

```
func switchChanged(cell: PreferenceCell) -> Void {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
         // rest of action code here
    }
}
```

The idea here is that the implemented delegate method should update the cell once the UISwithc is toggled, however a nil cell is always passed.  I set the delegate in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and then bind the switch to invoke the delegate method:

```
// Cell for row at index path, building the cell...
prefCell.delegate = self

// Create listener for each switch
prefCell.subscribed?.addTarget(self, 
                               action: "switchChanged:", 
                               forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

return prefCell
```

This block is called for each cell, I removed the method signature for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for clarity.

Why is a nil cell always being passed? Have I misunderstood something with the delegate pattern here?

Comment: Just speculating: could it be because the sender is actually a switch instead of the `PreferenceCell`?  If you declare `switchChanged` to accept any object, is something passed to it?

Comment: Your handler for the switch changed event should be in your custom cell class. You can configure it using IB if you are using prototype cells. That handler inside PreferenceCell.swift should call `self.delegate.switchChanged(self)`

Comment: You can't do it like that. The argument passed in to an action of a control is the control itself, so even though you say switchChanged(cell: PreferenceCell) what you really get is switchChanged(sender: UISwitch)

Comment: @rdelmar that makes sense thank-you.  Is there any other way I could achieve what I want using the delegate?

Comment: Why are you using a delegate in the first place? If you make the switch's target the controller, you can do what you want in the switch's action method. You can get the indexPath (inside the action method) using the table view method indexPathForRowAtPoint. See my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968942/prepareforsegue-passes-value-for-index-0-always/28973606#28973606, for how to do that.

Comment: see my previous question re using a delegate

Comment: thanks for your post - that should fix it :)